# Como exibir paginação com shortcodes no woocommerce, como o [Product_Category]

Tags: php, woocommerce

Estou usando o shortcode [Product_Category] para exibir os produtos na loja pela facilidade de combinar categorias, posso exibir por exemplo somente os produtos que pertencem ao mesmo tempo às categorias ERGOMETRIA e PROFISSIONAL e NOVO (se quiserem saber como faz isso me perguntem).

Mas o problema é que esse shortcode não dá opção de exibir paginação, ou seja se eu configurar para exibir apenas 12 produtos por página e eu tenho mais que 12 produtos, os outros produtos simplesmente não serão mostrados.

Depois de muita procura encontrei uma SOLUÇÃO que funcionou para resolver isso e vou postar como resposta pois muitas pessoas podem estar sofrendo com isso.

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de compartilhar esta solução com vocês, a solução foi dada por [klihelp no github]: https://gist.github.com/klihelp/7810337
O que funcionou para mim foi colocar o seguinte código no arquivo funcions.php do meu tema-child:

```
/**
* This code shows pagination for WooCommerce shortcodes when it's embeded on single pages.
* Include into functions.php.
*/
if ( defined('WC_VERSION') ) {
// ---------------------- WooCommerce active -------------------
/**
 * Set Pagination for shortcodes custom loop on single-pages.
 * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query' ); 
function kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Get paged from main query only
    // ! frontpage missing the post_type
    if ( is_main_query() && ( $query->query['post_type'] == 'product' ) || ! isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) ){

      if ( isset($query->query['paged']) ){
        $woocommerce_loop['paged'] = $query->query['paged'];
      }
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    $query->is_paged = true;
    $query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    $query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
}

/** Prepare Pagination data for shortcodes on pages
 * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
 */
add_action( 'loop_end', 'kli_query_loop_end' ); 
function kli_query_loop_end( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    // Cache data for pagination
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'] = $query->found_posts;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'] = $query->max_num_pages;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'] = $query->post_count;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'] = $query->current_post;
}
/**
 * Pagination for shortcodes on single-pages 
 * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', 'kli_wc_shortcode_pagination' ); 
function kli_wc_shortcode_pagination( $template_name ) {
    if ( ! ( $template_name === 'loop/loop-end.php' && is_page() ) ){
        return;
    }
    global $wp_query, $woocommerce_loop;
    if ( ! isset( $woocommerce_loop['pagination'] ) ){
        return;
    }
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
    $wp_query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'];
    $wp_query->found_posts = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'];
    $wp_query->post_count = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'];
    $wp_query->current_post = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'];

    // Custom pagination function or default woocommerce_pagination()
    kli_woocommerce_pagination();
}   
/**
 * Custom pagination for WooCommerce instead the default woocommerce_pagination()
 * @uses plugin Prime Strategy Page Navi, but added is_singular() on #line16
 */
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'kli_woocommerce_pagination', 10);
function kli_woocommerce_pagination() {
    woocommerce_pagination(); 
}
}// END WOOCOMMERCE
```

Comment: bacana. Depois de colocar esse código no funciona.php onde eu devo chamar pra funcionar na pág?